# Keeping a div selected and changing its values through a button

Tags: jquery

I have two div's, A and B. Both of them have numerical value 1. Now I have a 'Add' button. I want to select one div at a time and increase the value in it by clicking on Add. How to do this?

```
<div id="A">1</div>
<div id="B">1</div>

<input type='button' value="ADD" id="add">
```

Script

```
$("#add").on('click', function(){
   $(??).text($(??).text() + 1);
});
```

How do I link ADD button to the div i click on, and maintain the selection when I click on ADD.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: you can say that...learning by doing :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var $divs = $('div');
var $addButton = $("#add");

// On click on a div remove calss from eventually previous clicked div and add class to current clicked div
$divs.on('click', function () {
    var $divClicked = $(this);
    $divs.removeClass('has-been-clicked')
    $divClicked.addClass('has-been-clicked');
});

// On click on button, find previous marked div and play with it. If no div has been clicked yet, nothing happens
$addButton.on('click', function () {
    var $lastDivClicked = $divs.filter('.has-been-clicked').first();

    if ($lastDivClicked.length > 0) {
        var currentValue = parseInt($lastDivClicked.text());
        $lastDivClicked.text(++currentValue);
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kxMmA/7/

**EDIT**

@user1545024: Wow, you might review jQuery docs and manuals...
1. There is no function `.nearest()`
2. An ID (in your case `#main`) has to be unqiue.
3. When adding class `selected` you should remove this class from siblings first.
4. You need only one event handler as clicks on `.qty` and `.name` will bubble up the DOM to `#main`.
5. When using `.text()` and calculating with numbers you should use `parseInt()`, otherwise result will be appended text, so `$(".selected").text() + 1` gives not a number `2` but a string `11`.

See an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hdn6e/12/
and an (in my eyes) optimised fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hdn6e/13/

Comment: Nice and complete, maybe a tad elaborate, but you went through the trouble of making the `.has-been-clicked` CSS class and everything

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hdn6e/10/ can you make this work?? I have tried all your suggestions, but looks like there is really something wrong here. It just isnt working

Comment: ID should have a unique value in DOM elements, you have two `id="main"` divs, so that will be a problem. you should do a `class` instead. see this commented fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CMaaL/

Comment: @Simon- Can You make a limit for the increment.For example it should increment upto 20...?

Answer (score 1):

Add a class, .selected maybe, when clicking the div, then find it with `$('.selected')`

Comment: <div id="temp">1</div>   $('#temp').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });  whats wrong with this?? its not adding my class

Comment: This might be difficult to maintain since you'll have to go back and remove `selected` and add it to a different div when a new one is clicked.

Comment: not too hard to just find all with .selected and remove the class i think.

Comment: why is it not adding the class??

Comment: Try using `$("#temp").on('click',function(){...` instead of `click()`

Comment: you've got mismatching quotes in your fiddle: ".selected'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hdn6e/8/   nothing seems to be working..this is quite strange

Comment: you've still got mismatching quotes here: `$(".selected').text($(".selected").text() +1);`

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle with it](http://jsfiddle.net/hdn6e/4/)

```
var myDiv;
$("div").on('click', function(){myDiv = $(this)});

$("#add").click(function() {
    myDiv.text(parseInt(myDiv.text(),10)+1);
});
```

Comment: this way, both divs would be updated instead of just a "selected" one

Comment: when I click on 'add', add itself becomes the new myDiv??

Comment: when you click either `div#A` or `div#B` they become the `selected` div of sorts. Then you click the `#add` button and it increments your `selected` div

Comment: have tried everything but doesnt work. Whats wrong with this http://jsfiddle.net/hdn6e/10/

Answer (score 0):

another possibility is to create a variable that contains the div you last clicked.

Add click listeners to the divs to update your reference variable, and just address the div in your reference variable from the "add" button click handler.

```
var lastClickedDiv;

$("div").on('click', function()
{
  lastClickedDiv = $(this);
});

$("#add").on('click', function(){
   var newNumber = parseInt(lastClickedDiv.text()) + 1
   lastClickedDiv.text(newNumber);
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nUQPA/)

Comment: This doesn't work either. `lastClickedDiv` needs to be called from `jQuery` to access the `text()` method. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xkSC/)

Comment: Edited, funny thing. i assumed that `this` inside the context of the click handler returned a jquery object.

Comment: also added parseint, the example was just adding extra "1" strings to the value